# adding dynamically buttons in horizontal order

Tags: android, button

I'm trying  to add some buttons dynamically in horizontal order. I have tried several options and none of them worked.
What am i doing wrong?

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pickItem);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

String userName;
List<CheckBox> usersButtonList=new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
int i=0;
for(User user : users){
    userName=user.getName();
    CheckBox Userbutton = new CheckBox(this);
    usersButtonList.add(Userbutton);
    Userbutton.setText(userName);
    Userbutton.setId(i);
    Userbutton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isChecked=((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
            String s= (String)((CheckBox)v).getText();
            updateActiveUsers(isChecked,s);
        }
    });
    if(i!=0)
    {
        buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,(i-1));
    }
    layout.addView(Userbutton,buttonParams);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Try with a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation.

Comment: @EasyJoinDev How can I do that ? I have tried to use LinearLayout but it doesn't worked..

Comment: Substitute the `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: use horizontal scrollview

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with this. First, like @EasyJoin Dev said, substitute `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` in your layout xml and set the orientation to horizontal. It should look something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pickItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then change the two top lines in your code to

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pickItem);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Since you have `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` it will take the whole space available. Let me know if you need any more help or this doesn't work